# Django models, custom functions

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a simple application with Django. I realized that I am doing the same kind of operations very often. For example I often need to get all Article objects which have `isPublick = True`. So I am wondering, is it possible to define a `get_published` function in the model?

If the model looks like this (simplified)

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    isPublished = models.BooleandField()

    def get_active(self):
       return Article.objects.filter(isPublicshed = 1)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Can you suggest a way of implementing the function?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

What you probably want is a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

From the django docs:

```
        # An example of a custom manager called "objects".

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_fun_people(self):
        return self.filter(fun=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fun = models.BooleanField()
    objects = PersonManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

which then allows you to do something like:

```
>>> p1 = Person(first_name='Bugs', last_name='Bunny', fun=True)
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Person(first_name='Droopy', last_name='Dog', fun=False)
>>> p2.save()
>>> Person.objects.get_fun_people()
[<Person: Bugs Bunny>]
```

Comment: Good code example. Succinctly explained a part of django that previously seemed pointless to me (in my noobosity). +1.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning, that in order for this to work and avoid NameErrors, you need to write the manager class above the object class, for it to recognize it.

Answer (score 24):

As is stated in the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods), if you need to add custom *row-level* functionality to your objects, you need to define custom methods on your models. However, if what you are after is custom *table-wide* functionality (such as getting all Article objects that qualify certain conditions), you have to define custom methods on [model Managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) (much as *aciniglio* above points out in their answer).

Answer (score 20):

You can use the staticmethod decorator.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    isPublished = models.BooleandField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_active():
        return Article.objects.filter(isPublished = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! Answered my, different, question.

Comment: This should be a `classmethod` instead.