# Is there a faster way to do this?

Tags: django, django-models

I often want to grab one field from one table. So I do this:

```
tmp = my_model.objects.get(pk=5) //Or some other record...
myVar = tmp.myField
```

Now `myVar` holds the value I want. This two step process is annoying. Is there a one step way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need to get the value in an independent variable?  Typically, you'd just use the `model_instance.field_name` in your code without that second step.

Comment: Because using `model_instance.field_name` is a whole lot of typing if I need that value in ten different places within a chunk of code. Simply assigning `y=model_instance.field_name` makes typing easier :-)

Comment: i will refer to a post [on this site][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372016/django-models-custom-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myVar = my_model.objects.get(pk=5).myField
```

Comment: I should have thought of that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only concerned about one field, I'd recommend:

```
myVar = my_model.objects.values('myField').get(pk=5)['myField']
```

No need to put undue load on your DB.

Comment: it might have worked if it was: _myVar = my_model.objects. **filter** (pk=5).values('myField') **[0]** ['myField']_

Comment: Sorry. Yes, my ordering was off. `values` must come before `get`. Once you call `get` you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar = my_model.objects.filter(pk=5).values_list('myField', flat=True)[0]
```

Personally I see above as the most elegant way. It will `select` only `myField` from database and pass it to `myVar`