# Multiple Annotations Based on Different Filters In Django

Tags: django, filter, annotations, django-queryset

Say I had models like the following:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

I want to get a list of all companies and a count of how many of their units are "offline" and how many are "online" in a single query.

I know how to get a list of one or the other by:

```
offline = Company.objects.all().filter(unit__status="offline").annotate(offline_count=Count("unit"))
online = Company.objects.all().filter(unit__status="online").annotate(online_count=Count("unit"))
```

I would like to be able to access the resulting queryset object like:

```
companies[0].offline_count
companies[0].online_count
```

Is this possible?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372016/django-models-custom-functions

Comment: @slim_ch I don't think a custom manager will help here at all.  what Curtis needs are conditional aggregates, they are coming to Django in future https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030 https://github.com/django/django/pull/2496#discussion_r12729133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aggregate-if/

```
from django.db.models import Q
from aggregate_if import Count, Sum

Company.objects.annotate(
    online_count=Count('unit', only=Q(unit__status="online")),
    offline_count=Count('unit', only=Q(unit__status="offline")),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: django-aggregate-if is superceded by the same functionality being rolled into [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)