# Django custom manager dont work

Tags: python, django

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372016/django-models-custom-functions) question i wrote this code:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):
    def current(self):
        return self.filter(date_start < datetime.datetime.now()).filter(date_end > datetime.datetime.now())

class PlannedCourse(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(ECourse)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    ...
    objects = CourseManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course.name + ' ' + self.date_start.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M") + ' - ' + self.date_end.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

but when I try to run `PlannedCourse.objects.current()` I get the error:

> NameError: name 'date_start' is not defined.

I'm a newbie and don't understand why this happens :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [fields lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups): `__gt` instead of `>` and `__lt` instead of `<`:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):
    def current(self):
        return self.filter(date_start__lt=datetime.datetime.now(),
                           date_end__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Just missing `=`: `date_start__lt=datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an undefined python object (`date_start`) with a date in python. However, the goal of a queryset is to compare objects in the database. Even if `date_start` was defined, this would be the equivalent of calling `.filter(True)` or `.filter(False)`.

To tell Django to check in the database, you have to pass keyword arguments to the filter that are converted to a query by the ORM:

```
return self.filter(date_start__lt=datetime.datetime.now(),
                   date_end__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Note that you're not actually comparing `date_start` and `datetime.datetime.now()`, the `.filter` function uses `**kwargs`, and gets the following arguments as a dictionary:

```
{
    'date_start__lt': datetime.datetime.now(),
    'date_end__gt': datetime.datetime.now(),
}
```

The `__lt` and `__gt` are [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) that tell the queryset how to perform the comparison in the database.